# Placing an image behind the text in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

In LibO Writer, is there a way of placing an image *behind* the text, not as a watermark or a page-background image, but simply before the text?

In MS Word I can use the "Behind Text" option, as shown here:

[image]

but I've found no way to accomplish that same result in LibO Writer.

Comment: Format --> Wrap --> In Background?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. But I have to give the text a "no fill" highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double click on image > Wrap > Select " In Background"

[image: Add image]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the image to open its context menu.

Inside that, select **Arrange > To Background**.

[image: LibreOffice 5 Writer image context menu]

As result, you see that the image is behind the text, without any white box around.

[image: text over image]

*Update:* In LibreOffice 6, choose **Wrap > In background**.

Comment: Libre office 6 option does not exist, on a .jpg image anyway.

Comment: Context menu / wrap / in background, is working.